# How to apply MVVM on ASP.NET with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, mvvm

Is there anyway to implement `MVVM` design pattern in client side of `Asp.net` with `MVC` applications?

Comment: KnockoutJs allows to implement MVVM on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds contradictory. ASP.NET MVC (as it name suggests) implements the MVC pattern. If you want to use the MVVM pattern in a web application you could implement it yourself on top of ASP.NET or use an existing framework such as [`ASP.NET MVVM`](http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/).

If you are talking about client side MVVM, there are gazillions of javascript frameworks (I've already lost track of their number, because they grow like mushrooms everyday) you could use: [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/), [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/), ... For example ASP.NET MVC 4 comes bundled with knockoutjs and is using it for its SPA template.

Comment: Yes. I need the client side MVVM. I have edited question.

Comment: Oh, then you have a vast choice of fultitude of frameworks which are server side agnostic :-) ASP.NET MVC 4 comes with konckoutjs out-of-the-box.